# Is there a way to upload a document from one document library to another on different farm?

Tags: best-practices

we are planning on a publishing functionality for our SP2013 site. 
(please note that we are not using the cross-site publishing feature, but ideally we are implementing similar concept)

There are 2 farms. The first farm has 2 site collections (one for each department).

The 2nd farm has 2 site collection as well (one for each department).

Managers upload documents into a document library on FARM1 on any one of the departments site collection. Once they are published we want to upload them into a document library on FARM2 on the respective site collection. What is the best practice to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is create event receiver using Visual Studio.
After document loaded to library, event receiver must programmatically make copy to another farm.

Comment: Is workflow a possible solution, ? I am more inclined towards using OOTB solutions.

Comment: see into using the Copy.asmx web service provided by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to doing it manually, the Send To functionality can be used to do this. I've set up a manual "publishing" process on past sites that allows a user to send a copy of the document to a library on a different web application/farm. Obviously, the user must have permissions to write to the destination library but otherwise the Send To is an easy way to do this - takes the user through a short wizard.

In my case, I was setting up the Send To destination for each library up manually, but you could also set up a global Send To destination in CA.